# Having trouble with Knights Tour in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knights-tour

I'm trying to the knights tour problem as an exercise in recursion since I have not used it in awhile, but my script does not seem to find a solution and only goes as high as 56 moves. Any tips to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
class KnightsTour
def initialize
    board = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
    8.times do |i|
        board[i] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    end
    tour(0,0,board)
end

def tour(x,y,board,current_move=0)
    puts board if current_move == 64

    return if board[x] == nil || 
              board[x][y] == nil || 
              board[x][y] != 0 || 
              x < 0 ||
              y < 0 ||
              current_move == 64

    current_move +=1
    board[x][y] = current_move

    tour(x+2, y+1, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x+2, y-1, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x+1, y-2, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x-1, y-2, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x-1, y+2, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x+1, y+2, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x-2, y+1, board.dup, current_move)
    tour(x-2, y-1, board.dup, current_move)
end
end

KnightsTour.new
```

Comment: `tour(x+2, y-1, board, current_move)` will try the cell `2, 6` assiming `[x,y] == [0,0]` because ruby allows the “second from the end” element to be addressed as `array[-2]`.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! Updating the return statement to account for that looks to be getting me 1 more move to 57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you only use one `board` object for all the recursions. You should use a copy of `board` anytime you try a move. `dup` produces a shallow copy, and isn't enough to duplicate the board.

Another problem might be that the bruteforce approach is too slow because of exponential growth (8 moves at every iteration, even if you stop early for some).

The usual approach is to pick the cell having the fewest possibilities as the next move.

Comment: Starting with 3×3 board and tracking what happens would be another good advice.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It's not possible to solve a 3x3 board : how would you land in the middle square?

Comment: It should not matter, first 10 problems with this approach would arise already on 3×3 :)

Comment: Thanks! I was misunderstanding how Ruby's parameter passing words, I'm now duping the board when I pass it. I'm hoping to get the brute force solution down, then work to improve its efficiency.

Comment: @xxyyxx: `dup` isn't enough: `a = [[0,0],[0,0]]; b=a.dup; b[0][0]=1; a`

Comment: Thanks Eric, I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction rather than just offering up the solution. I'm now using Marshal.load(Marshal.dump board) and that seems to work considering how long the script has been executing for. Now I'll work on turning the brute force approach into something more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_safe?(solution, x, y)
   x >= 0 && x < solution.length && y>= 0 && y < solution.length && solution[x][y] == -1
end

def solve_nt_helper(size, solution, curr_x, curr_y, num, xmoves, ymoves)
    return true if num == size * size
    size.times.each do |i|
        # p "i:#{i}"
        next_x = curr_x + xmoves[i]
        next_y = curr_y + ymoves[i]
        if is_safe?(solution, next_x, next_y)
            solution[next_x][next_y] = num
            return true if solve_nt_helper(size, solution, next_x, next_y, num + 1, xmoves, ymoves)
  
            solution[next_x][next_y] = -1
        end
    end
    # p "failed at num #{num}"
    false
end

def solve_nt(n)
    xmoves = [2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2]
    ymoves = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1]
    solution = Array.new(n) { Array.new(n) { -1 } }
    solution[0][0] = 0
    solution.each do |row|
      p row
    end
    return 'invalid' unless solve_nt_helper(n, solution, 0, 0, 1, xmoves, ymoves)
    solution.each do |row|
      p row
    end
    solution
end

n = 8
require 'memory_profiler'
report = MemoryProfiler.report do
solve_nt(n)
end
report.pretty_print
```

here is a ruby version that works. The trick of this solution is

1. don't put any debugging message in the recursive method.
2. pass xmoves, and ymoves as variable to the recursive method.don't define a constant
   KNIGHTS_MOVES = [[2, 1],[2, -1], [-2, 1],[-2, -1],[1, 2],[1, -2], [-1, 2], [-1, -2]]
   and iterate over it in solve_nt_helper. sizes.each would generate a lot of Enumerator objects, but iterater over constant  seems slows the whole process down.

trick 1 also seems to applicalbe to java and python.did not try item2 for java and python. The algorithm is borrowed from [geekstogeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-knights-tour-problem-backtracking-1/)